# Google ad manager api slow when not debugging (c#)

Tags: c#, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

We are currently experiencing a rather odd behavior in our google ad manager c# client.
We are using `Google.Dfp` nuget package.

Here's the code we are using:

```
reportQuery.dimensions = new Dimension[] {
  Dimension.DATE, dimension
};
var reportJob = new ReportJob {
  reportQuery = reportQuery
};
reportJob = reportService.runReportJob(reportJob);
// Set download options.
var options = new ReportDownloadOptions {
  exportFormat = ExportFormat.XML,
    useGzipCompression = true
};
var reportUtilities = new ReportUtilities(reportService, reportJob.id) {
  reportDownloadOptions = options
};
var dimensionResponse = new List < DimensionResponse > ();
XDocument xmlDoc = null;
using(var response = reportUtilities.GetResponse()) {
  using(var oReader = new StreamReader(response.DecompressedStream)) {
    xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(oReader);
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (ReportResponse), new XmlRootAttribute("Report"));
    var xml = xmlDoc.ToString();
    using(var sr = new StringReader(xml)) {
      var result = (ReportResponse) serializer.Deserialize(sr);
      if (result.ReportData.DataSet.Row != null) {
        dimensionResponse = result.ReportData.DataSet.Row.Select(x => new DimensionResponse {
          DateString = x.Column[0].Val,
            Name = x.Column[1].Val,
            Impressions = int.Parse(x.Column[hasIdColumn ? 3 : 2].Val, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            Clicks = int.Parse(x.Column[hasIdColumn ? 4 : 3].Val, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            CTR = x.Column[hasIdColumn ? 5 : 4].Val,
            ActiveViewViewableImpressions = int.Parse(x.Column[hasIdColumn ? 6 : 5].Val, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            ActiveViewViewableImpressionsRate = x.Column[hasIdColumn ? 7 : 6].Val
        }).ToList();
      }
    }
  }
}
return dimensionResponse;
```

The problem occurrs at this line:

```
using(var response = reportUtilities.GetResponse())
```

When we are debugging step by step, it takes aprox 2 seconds for api to return a response, but when we remove a breakpoint and try without it, it takes around 32 seconds for the function to finish.
Same slowness occurs in release mode on production server.

We thought first time was slow and all other tests were faster because google cached reports on the backend, but that was not the case since we managed to reproduce issue on non cached reports with different dates.

Any idea what would cause this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Here are somethings you can try from [appengine latency here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/troubleshooter/latency)

Did you put your production key in the code, also did you exceed the rate limits.

- Code optimization Some ways that you can optimize code on App Engine
  to reduce latency:
- Offline work: Use Cloud Tasks so that user requests do not block
  waiting for completion of work such as sending mail.
- Asynchronous API calls: Ensure that your code is not blocked waiting
  for an API call to complete. Libraries such as ndb offer built-in
  support for this.
- Batch API calls: The batch version of API calls is usually faster
  than sending individual calls.
- Denormalize data models: Reduce the latency of calls made to the data
  persistence layer by denormalizing your data models.